# copy image from Clipboard - React hooks Ctrl + V

Tags: reactjs, upload, hook, image-view

actualmente estoy desarrollando el pegar imágenes desde el portapapeles con Ctrl + V mediante react hook. Me funciona normal seleccionando el archivo lo guardo en el state y si desisto lo elimino. Muestro lo creado:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

let styleImage = {
  height: '10em',
  width: 'auto '
}

export default () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  return (

    <div className="form-group col-md-4">
      <div className="row">
        <label className="">Imagen</label>
        {image && (
          <div className="col-12 text-center">
            <img alt="not fount" style={styleImage} src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} />
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="col-9 mt-2">
          <input
            type="file"
            className="form-control col-8"
            id="imagen"
            onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
            required
          />
        </div>
        {image && (
          <div className="col-3 mt-2">
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => setImage('')}  >Remove</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Eso es lo que quiero conseguir pero con Ctrl + V para eso según leí varios foros recomiendan usar esta librería `@rpldy`, me parace genial pero no he logrado entender como se captura la imagen en el state.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Uploady, {
  useItemStartListener,
  useItemFinalizeListener,
} from "@rpldy/uploady";
import { getMockSenderEnhancer } from "@rpldy/mock-sender";
import UploadDropZone from "@rpldy/upload-drop-zone";
import withPasteUpload from "@rpldy/upload-paste";
import UploadPreview from "@rpldy/upload-preview";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import e from "express";

const mockSenderEnhancer = getMockSenderEnhancer();

const PreviewContainer = styled.div`
  margin-top: 20px;

  img {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
`;

const StyledDropZone = styled(UploadDropZone)`
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

const StyledInput = styled.input`
  width: 400px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 10px 0;
`;

const PasteUploadDropZone = withPasteUpload(StyledDropZone);

const PasteInput = withPasteUpload(StyledInput);

const UploadStatus = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

  useItemStartListener(() => setStatus("Cargando..."));
  useItemFinalizeListener(() => setStatus("¡Cargada!"));

  return status;
};

export default () => {

  const [image, setImage] = useState('');

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Uploady debug enhancer={mockSenderEnhancer}>
          <h2 className="text-center">Cargue de imágenes</h2>
          <Col md={12}>
            <PreviewContainer>
              <UploadPreview />
            </PreviewContainer>
          </Col>
          <Col md={8}>
            <PasteInput
              onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
              extraProps={{
                placeholder: "Pegar img desde portapapeles (Ctrl + V)",
              }}
            />
            <UploadStatus />
          </Col>
          <Col md={4}>
            <button onClick={() => setImage('')}>Remove</button>
          </Col>

        </Uploady>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Ese onChange ahí donde está no hace nada, sin embargo lo puse para dar un contexto de lo que quiero hacer.
Bueno quedo atento a sus comentarios.
Por cierto se ven diferentes porque el primero es un proyecto que funciona y último es uno nuevo que estoy creando.

Comment: ¿Y si creas una función handle para el onChange, en vez de una función anónima en render time? saludos

Comment: No sabría cómo hacerlo

Comment: Sin embargo estuve viendo documentación y encontré este personaje, dejo su repositorio: https://gist.github.com/yoavniran y claramente la documentación se encuentra en NPM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de trabajar en otros proyectos e investigar un poco, porque "El que persevera hasta el fin, este será salvo" encontré este post [react-typescript-handle-oncopy-oncut-and-events](https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-typescript-handle-oncopy-oncut-and-onpaste-events/) y me dí cuenta que así como lo hice con el componente de adjuntar imagen puede hacerlo aquí también capturando el valor de e.clipboardData, claro también capturo la posición 0, y después validé si el tipo es imagen.

```
const handleChange = async (e) => {
    var item = await e.clipboardData.items[0];

    if (item.type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
      setImage(item.getAsFile())
    } else {
      alert("Solo se aceptan imágenes");
    }
}
```

Si notan fué realmente muy cencillo, el input lo declaré `typt="text"` y en el `onPaste` llamó la función modificadora `onPaste={handleChange}`. Comparto este post porque para resolverlo no encontré mucha documentación tan evidente.
comparto el componente completo.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

let styleImage = {
  height: '10em',
  width: 'auto '
}

export default () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');


  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    var item = await e.clipboardData.items[0];

    if (item.type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
      setImage(item.getAsFile())
    } else {
      alert("Solo se aceptan imágenes");
    }
  }

  return (

    <div className="form-group col-md-4">
      <div className="row">
        <label className="">Imagen</label>
        {image && (
          <div className="col-12 text-center">
            <img alt="not fount" style={styleImage} src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} />
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="col-9 mt-2">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder='Pegar Imagen Ctrl + V'
            className="form-control col-8"
            id="image"
            onPaste={handleChange}
            required
          />
        </div>
        {image && (
          <div className="col-3 mt-2">
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => {
              setImage('');
              document.getElementById('image').value = null;
            }}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```